# Python shell script open less with +F option

Tags: python, linux, scripting, less-unix

I have the following Python script, all seems to work how I want it to, except for the following:

- less opens with the option -F, this will follow the file like Tail would.
- to inspect (move through) the file the user has to ctrl + c to send an interrrupt.
- when sending the ctrl +c (interrupt) this gets send to the python script, which will terminate the less process.

Is there a way to be able to use ctrl +c in the less window and not terminating the script while doing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import subprocess as sp
try:
    if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
        print "Choose an EngineID!"
    engineID = sys.argv[1]

    logdir='/data/work/silverlocal-%s/log' % engineID
    logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('log-%s' % engineID)])
    lastlog = (logdir + "/" + logfiles[-1])

    os.spawnlpe(os.P_WAIT, 'less', 'less', '+F', '-K', (lastlog), os.environ)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Should there not be a nice solution using my current script, maybe someone can advice me a more suitable solution, language does not matter much.

Cheers,

Phillip

SOLUTION:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import subprocess as sp
import signal

if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
print "Choose an EngineID!"
engineID = sys.argv[1]

logdir='/data/awork/silverlocal-%s/log' % engineID
logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('log-%s' % engineID)])
lastlog = (logdir + "/" + logfiles[-1])
old_action = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
os.spawnlpe(os.P_WAIT, 'less', 'less', '+F', (lastlog), os.environ)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, old_action)    # restore old signal disposition
print("I'm still running!")
```

Comment: open it in a new tab/window taking focus from where the python script is running

Comment: You should probably be using `subprocess` instead of `os` to launch processes. It makes things such as killing processes much easier

Comment: Hi, I don't actually want to kill the process, I want to send the interrupt signal to less, not to the Python script

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, do you mean open a new Terminal tab? This is not really an option as users will also be using Putty to start this script, or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ignoring the `SIGINT` signal and remove the `-K` less option:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import signal
import subprocess as sp

try:
    if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
        print "Choose an EngineID!"
    engineID = sys.argv[1]

    logdir='/data/work/silverlocal-%s/log' % engineID
    logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('log-%s' % engineID)])
    lastlog = (logdir + "/" + logfiles[-1])

    old_action = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    os.spawnlpe(os.P_WAIT, 'less', 'less', '+F', (lastlog), os.environ)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, old_action)    # restore old signal disposition
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

print("I'm still running!")
```

The `try...except` is no longer useful, so you could probably remove it.

To be honest my recollection of signal handling is a bit foggy, and I'm not 100% sure why this works. Obviously ignoring SIGINT (generated by Ctrl+C) prevents Python acting on the signal, but the spawned process should inherit it parent's signal disposition. Possibly `less` sets up its own signal handlers, and maybe this is why it works.

Comment: Hey mhawke, thanks for the reply and the answer, it works like a charm. Much appreciated! I'll edit my question to include the solution you proposed.

Comment: @PhillipParrin  Great. Let me know if there are any unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Ok will do, at the moment it is doing exactly what I needed. Not closing the spawn less process upon ctrl+c. Again really appreciated!